# API-like page with list of my questions

Tags: support

Quite a while back, I found a link to a SO page which I found quite interesting, but I can't find it anymore.

It was a text-only page, and stored basically the same thing as the stats dropdown in the top bar of SE sites (the third button in the top bar). It also featured some other stats like the amount of times you had passed 200 rep, the badges you had, and some other things I believe. It had some kind of url like `http://stackoverflow.com/stats`, or something like that (a short url), but I tried things like `/stats`, `/user`, `/api`, but none of those worked.

If anybody knows what I'm talking about, could you please post a link to that page?

Comment: Are you by any chnace looking for http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is most probably the reputation page, which can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation